# Making a file from a form cannot post error

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am currently coding a node js with AWS code thank takes a string from a HTML textbox and transfers it to another python file and return the compilation of it.

The node.js file is as follows

```
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/myform', function(req, res) {
    var myText = req.query.mytext; 
    res.send('Your Text:' +myText);

    fs.writeFile('app.py',myText,function(err) {
       if(err) throw err;
    });
});

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000!'));
```

And index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:Blue">Docker</h1>

    <div id="floating-panel">
        <form action="/myform" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mytext" required />
            <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon submitting my for I get the error "Cannot POST /myform" and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: you might want to use `app.post` instead of `app.get`

Comment: can you please post that as a solution I feel really foolish and i want to upvote you. Follow up question would be what is causing 'myText' to be undefined

Comment: no problem, welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply use `app.post` instead of `app.get`